# Where move functions from template in Laravel

Tags: php, function, templates, laravel, laravel-blade

I would like show nested list in my blade template.
If I want quickly display nested list I have to do it by recursive. I created in my template function named renderNode(). But this global function im my template is not good idea and practise. I would like reorganize it.

Do you know good practise, how to organize my code?

```
<?php
function renderNode($node) {
echo "<li class='dd-item dd3-item' data-id='$node->id'>";
echo "<div class='dd-handle dd3-handle'>Drag</div>
    <div class='dd3-content'>
        $node->name
        <span class='pull-right categories-actions'>
            <i class='fa fa-plus-square-o delete-category' title=''></i>
            <i class='fa fa-cogs delete-category' title=''></i>
            <i class='fa fa-trash-o delete-category' title=''></i>
        </span>
    </div>";

if ( $node->children()->count() > 0 ) {
    echo "<ol class='dd-list'>";
    foreach($node->children as $child) renderNode($child);
    echo "</ol>";
}
echo "</li>";
}
?>
<div id="content" class="col-lg-10 col-sm-11">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div>
            <button id="add-new-category" class="btn btn-    primary">@lang('categories.new_category')</button>
        </div>

        <div class="dd" id="nestable3">
            <ol class="dd-list">
                @if(isset($categories))
                @foreach($categories as $category)

                <?php renderNode($category); ?>

                @endforeach
                @endif

            </ol>
        </div>
    </div><!--/col-->
</div><!--/row-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this is not good practice.  The best thing to do would be to put this code in a model of your choosing.  Models > Category would be the most appropriate imo.  Just make a public function in your Category model like so...

```
public function renderNode($node) 
{
// place code here

return something here;
}
```

then call the model function in your blade template

```
<?php Category::renderNode( $node ) ?>
```

You can pass $node through the Make::view in your route using with.

**However**, you might want to consider a different approach.  Like this...

```
@if ( $node->children()->count() > 0 )
<ol class='dd-list'>
@foreach ($node->children as $child)
  {{ Category::renderNode($child) }}
@endforeach
</ol>
@endif
```

Comment: No it's not keep your markup in the blade file and the heavy logic in the model.  Functions only are used to calculate something and return a value.  You can use if else statements to decide what to do depending on the returned value.  Looking at your code, you don't need a function at all.  You can pass pass variables to the view using View::make()->with().  Then in blade use the if, else to determine what to output.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how can do it. Could you show full example ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol class="dd-list">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <li class='dd-item dd3-item' data-id="$category->id">
        <div class='dd-handle dd3-handle'>Drag</div>
            <div class='dd3-content'>
            {{ $node->name }}
            <span class='pull-right categories-actions'>
                <i class='fa fa-plus-square-o delete-category' title=''></i>
                <i class='fa fa-cogs delete-category' title=''></i>
                <i class='fa fa-trash-o delete-category' title=''></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        @if ( $node->children()->count() > 0 )
            @foreach ($node->children as $child)
                <li class='dd-item dd3-item' data-id='$child->id'>
                <div class='dd-handle dd3-handle'>Drag</div>
                <div class='dd3-content'>
                {{ $child->name }}
                <span class='pull-right categories-actions'>
                    <i class='fa fa-plus-square-o delete-category' title=''></i>
                    <i class='fa fa-cogs delete-category' title=''></i>
                    <i class='fa fa-trash-o delete-category' title=''></i>
                </span>
            @endforeach
        @endif
        </div>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ol>
```

something like this

Comment: Did you pass the variable in the view?  Using with?

Comment: Yes I pass the variable using with.